# Merging and intercalating elements from two parents

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have two sections with a dynamic number of elements inside.
I want to take those two sections, merge them and intercalate their items.

Originally it would be something like this:

```
<section class="first">
 <div>One</div>
 <div>Two</div>
 <div>Three</div>
</section>

<section class="second">
 <div>Four</div>
 <div>Five</div>
 <div>Six</div>
</section>
```

And the desired output:

```
<section class="merged">
 <div>One</div>
 <div>Four</div>
 <div>Two</div>
 <div>Five</div>
 <div>Three</div>
 <div>Six</div>
</section>
```

Here's my attempt so far but I can't manage to show the result:

```
var array1 = $( ".first div" ).toArray()
var array2 = $( ".second div" ).toArray()

var arrayCombined = $.map(array1, function(v, i) { return [v, array2[i]]; });
```

Does someone know how can I achieve that?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the DIVs in one section, and append that DIV followed by a DIV from the second section.

The second append always uses `.first()` because it's removing the first DIV from the second section, so the next corresponding DIV will then be first.

```js
$(".first > div").each(function() {
  $(".merged").append(this);
  $(".merged").append($(".second > div").first());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="first">
  <div>One</div>
  <div>Two</div>
  <div>Three</div>
</section>

<section class="second">
  <div>Four</div>
  <div>Five</div>
  <div>Six</div>
</section>

<section class="merged">
</section>
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks a lot. Right now the output is five, one, four, two... Is there a way to make it start like how I proposed before? One, Five, Two Four... and so on.

Comment: What is the logic in your ordering?

Comment: It basically intercalate the items in numeric order. 1st from 1st section, 1st from 2nd, etc

Comment: Oh, the problem is that I'm removing element from the second section, so the indexes don't match any more.

Comment: I fixed it. I still don't understand why `Five` should be before `Four` in the result.

Comment: Is your example output wrong? Why is it One, Five instead of One, Four?

Answer (score 0):

And this decision is from me. This is a `javascript` solution. `forEach()` method is used:

```
Array.from(sections_for_merge_section).forEach(function(sections_for_merge_sectionArray) { 
   merged.append(sections_for_merge_sectionArray.cloneNode(true));
});
```

The `section` in which you need to add the merged sections is added by the code:

```
let merged = document.createElement('section');
```

Also, the `cloneNode(true)` method is used to copy data into the created section:

```
...sections_for_merge_sectionArray.cloneNode(true)...
```

```js
window.onload = function() {
  let sections_for_merge = document.querySelector('.sections_for_merge');
  let sections_for_merge_section = document.querySelectorAll('.sections_for_merge section div');
  let merged = document.createElement('section');
  
  merged.className = 'merged';
  document.body.append(merged);
  
  Array.from(sections_for_merge_section).forEach(function(sections_for_merge_sectionArray) { 
    merged.append(sections_for_merge_sectionArray.cloneNode(true));
  });  
}
```

```html
<div class="sections_for_merge">
  <section class="first">
   <div>One</div>
   <div>Two</div>
   <div>Three</div>
  </section>
  <section class="second">
   <div>Four</div>
   <div>Five</div>
   <div>Six</div>
  </section>
</div>
<br>
<p>Below is the created element <strong>div</strong> with merged divs:</p>
<br>
```